# docker push: unauthorized: The client does not have permission to push to the repository

Tags: docker, artifactory, docker-machine

I have a private docker registry on Artifactory and I am trying to push an image with docker from my Windows 7 machine. I am using docker-machine (e.g. boot2docker) with docker running in a Virtualbox VM.

I have already successfully pushed a docker image from another Linux machine. When I ssh into the docker-machine using `docker-machine ssh default` and try to push an image from there everything works.

However from my Windows 7 machine I get the following error:

> 277ef3f664a2: Preparing
>   8ccbb058a746: Preparing
>   unauthorized: The client does not have permission to push to the repository.

The user I use to login with `docker login` is an administrator on Artifactory, so I don't think this is really a permission issue.

The Artifactory is using self-signed certificates, I am not sure if that might be the issue.

Comment: What method are you using to configure the reverse proxy for docker with Artifactory?
SubDomain/Port/RepositoryPath?

Comment: The docker repository runs on port 8443, am not aware of any additional RepositoryPath, but since I did not setup this artifactory, I don't know for sure.